# rectangle overlap code not working as expected (returning true when no overlap)

Tags: java, libgdx, rectangles, collision

(edit) never mind... 
    if(r.overlaps(b.getBounds()));
should read
    if(r.overlaps(b.getBounds()))

!

I am trying to check for an overlap of two rectangles using libgdx, and the function is returning true when, unless I've completely lost the plot, there is no overlap at all:

```
        for(Block b:this.collidableBlocks)
        {
            if(b==null) continue;
            Rectangle r = Bullet.this.getBounds();
            if(r.overlaps(b.getBounds()));
            {
                Bullet.this.destroy();
                break;
            }
        }
```

When I break in the debugger, the bounds of r are:
x = 174.0
y = 30.25068
w = 0.3
h = 0.05

and the bounds of b are:
x = 0
y = 0
w = 1
h = 1

yes the .overlaps() function is returning true

The code for .overlaps() is as follows:

```
 public boolean overlaps (Rectangle r) {
    return x < r.x + r.width && x + width > r.x && y < r.y + r.height && y + height > r.y;
}
```

Comment: If your declared values are correct, it is quite obvious that function .overlaps(Rectangle) should return false, because first component in the return statement (x < r.x + r.width) should evaluate to false (174 < 0 + 1). Why don't you break/step-in to the .overlaps(Rectangle) function and check if you get the appropriate values there? Other than that, I don't seem to find any problems with your collision detection code.

Comment: never mind... it's a bit of brain fade... the if statement is terminated with a semi colon :$

Comment: Oooohhh... I feel you :D "Missing comma" bug :) Goood luck anyways!

Comment: Post it as an answer so you can mark it as solved. If you have a "bug" like this always try to debug your code and enter the methods. In those methods then you can check if the values are like they should be. By doing this you also find out type errors like this. I looked a while here til i ve found the `;`, even if i ve allready read your comment :P

Answer (score 0):

never mind... it's a bit of brain fade... the if statement is terminated with a semi colon :$

```
 //this
 if(r.overlaps(b.getBounds()));
 //should say 
 if(r.overlaps(b.getBounds()))
```